# Win8: Share functional

Tags: winrt-xaml

I need to share info to the social application through windows share. What I do: install application (Twitter, FB, Latermark) and try to post different types of information. But I want to check what user clicks (Twitter or Facebook, etc) and in this case I will post different description, add images....
For example if user select Twitter I will add short description
"I am playing .....bal-bla-bla"
If he shares through Mail it will be longer
"I am playing .....bal-bla-bla(very long description)"
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/cb31c30a-1a0a-4311-96b2-5e02459ba217 - thanks for quick response and explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Share source application has no knowledge about Share receiver, and it is by design. What even more important - you can't change share content after share contract is started.